# Finding difference and concatenation of two dataframes in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 dataframes with the same 4 fields and which may or may not have different values only under the 4th field. How do I create a new dataframe with five fields where only entries with differing values are stored and the 4th and 5th columns display the corresponding contrasting values?

Comment: There is same number of rows in each DataFrame?

Comment: Can you add some data samples?

Comment: @jezrael Yes there is same number of rows

Answer (score 1):

I think need first create one `DaatFrame` by [`join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) and then filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, 2], 'b': [10, 17, 2], 'c': [0, 2, 0], 'd': list('adb')})
print (df1)
   a   b  c  d
0  1  10  0  a
1  2  17  2  d
2  2   2  0  b

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, 2], 'b': [10, 17, 2], 'c': [0, 2, 0], 'd': list('edc')})
print (df2)
   a   b  c  d
0  1  10  0  e
1  2  17  2  d
2  2   2  0  c

df = df1.join(df2[['d']], rsuffix='_')
print (df)
   a   b  c  d d_
0  1  10  0  a  e
1  2  17  2  d  d
2  2   2  0  b  c

df = df[df['d'] != df['d_']]
print (df)   
   a   b  c  d d_
0  1  10  0  a  e
2  2   2  0  b  c
```